# Full Calendar messing with my timezone when formatting date

Tags: jquery, datetime, timezone, format, fullcalendar

I am implementing full calendar - 
My .js file looks like this -

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header : {
            left:"prev,next today",
            center:"title",
            right:"agendaWeek,agendaDay"
            },
        timezone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDaySlot: false,
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        eventSources: [{
            type: "POST",
            url: 'cal_func.php',
            async: false,
            data: {action:'get_slots', userid:$userxid, which:$calaction},
            success: function(data){
                if(data.length != 0){
                    return data;
                }else{

                }
            }
        }],
        select: function(start, end){
            if(parseInt($('#mentor').val()) == 1){
                setNotifyMsg('');
            }else{
                if($calaction == 1){
                    var startDate = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");

                    var endDate = end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
                    $title = $('#titleVal').val();
                    var out = addAptToDB($title, startDate, endDate, 0);
                    if(out == 1){
                        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',{title: $title, start: start, end: end},true);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                }else{
                    setNotifyMsg('You cannot add an appointment this way.');
                }
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        }
})
```

Now when I am selecting a time slot to book an appointment in my calendar from say from 9am-10am. It is booking a timeslot between 9.12 - 10.12 am.

I debugged, and the culprit seems to be this line in 'select' -

```
var startDate = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
```

Before formatting, this is the input -
[image]

After formatting by moment.js, this is the output -
[image]

It uses format of moment.js and returns bad value. Where am I going wrong? How can I fix this.

- Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, MM- specifies the month number. You have to use correct format like 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'.

[Formats in moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)